# Pandas extract substring between two characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column in pandas which contains a long piece of text

```
            Value_column
Car:"Ford",Colour:"Black", Price:2000,
```

I'd like to split this into three columns

So it would look like

```
Car     Colour    Price
Ford    Black     2000
```

I've been able to do it for the first split using

```
df['Car']=df['Value_column].str.split("Car",expand=True).iloc[:,1:]
df['Car']=df['Car'].str[0:5]
```

But can't figure out a neat way of doing it for all values. The tricky bit I'm finding is telling the code when to end. It only works for Ford because I know Ford is 4 letters long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your key/values don't contain `:`/`,` characters, you can [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (df['Value_column']
 .str.extractall(r'\s*([^:,]+):\s*\"?([^:,]+?)\"?\s*(?:,|\s*$)')
 .droplevel('match').pivot(columns=0, values=1)
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   Price   Car Colour
0   2000  Ford  Black
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t6L1SH/1)

Comment: I improved a bit the regex to avoid dangling spaces

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, using the [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/okCaVe/1) made by *@mozway* :

```
import re

pat = r'([^:,]+):\"?([^:,]+?)\"?(?:,|\s*$)' # mozway

out = pd.DataFrame([dict(re.findall(pat, s)) for s in df["Value_column"]])
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    Car Colour  Price
0  Ford  Black   2000
```